# Python printing multiple lines?

Tags: python

So I am a beginner to Python (previous experience with Java), and I was creating a simple OOP program. Here is my class:

```
from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input


class Info:

    def startGame(self):
        name = raw_input('What is your name?\n')
        age = raw_input("What is your age?\n")
        color = raw_input("What is your favorite color\n")
        print("Your name is %s, your age is %s, and your favorite color is %s" % (name, age, color))
        return Info


class App:

    def build(self):
        game_app = Info()
        game_app.startGame()
        return game

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = App()
    game = Info()
    obj.build()
```

This is the output:

```
Your name is Chris
, your age is 18
, Sand your favorite color is Red
```

I am confused as to why it is printing on 3 lines? Is there any way to print this onto a single line?

Comment: What is the difference between `Tools.scripts.treesync.raw_input` function and the standardlib raw_input (which should strip newline characters)?

Comment: None of what you posted is Javascript. Please don't post it as a Javascript snippet.

Comment: You should either use `input` instead of `raw_input` or use `name.strip()` to remove the trailing newline (also for the other variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `raw_input` you're importing is keeping the CRLF in the input you entered. Why not use the built-in `input()` function (you are using Python 3, right)?

```
>>> from Tools.scripts.treesync import raw_input
>>> raw_input("> ")
> abc
'abc\n'
>>> input("> ")
> abc
'abc'
```

Also, Python is not Java. No need to put everything in classes.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes? OP is not using the built-in `raw_input()` - there isn't one in Python 3, and the `print()` syntax he's using suggests that that's what he is on.

Comment: I was wondering the same (I didn't downvote, btw). Isn't this answer also correct?

Comment: Sorry, missed the `raw_input` import.

Comment: Hey, OP here. Since I am coming from Java I feel the need to put everything in a class. What would the best way to organize this file be then?

Comment: Just define the functions on their own.

Comment: Ok. When exactly SHOULD I be storing certain functions in a seperate class?

Comment: @Waldxn: A class should never be used as a holder for functions. Java only does that because of the inflexible structure of Java programs. The operations supported by instances of a class should be methods of the class, and some closely-related functions (such as alternate constructors) may be appropriate as classmethods or staticmethods, but if you just want somewhere to group a bunch of functions together, that's what modules are for.

Comment: Usually you store functions in modules (each Python file is a module). Adding a function to a class makes sense for object methods, i. e. methods that are only useful for a specific object. In your case the class doesn't do anything besides harboring a function - that's not how Python "works". It may be different with complex objects, but your question is a bit too broad for an answer in a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `raw_input`, which includes a line ending to the string, you can just use `input()` to obtain the string without a line ending.

Comment: It's not the standard `raw_input()` but rather something imported from a library.